# What is the `data` object passed to a Codec's `decode` method?

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-file

I'd like to write a `Codec` plugin to enable LogStash to decode a binary data format.

[The official documentation for writing a `Codec`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_codec_plugin.html#_literal_decode_literal_method) shows that I need to define a `decode` method that accepts a single parameter: a variable called `data`.

I'm new to both LogStash and Ruby. Having worked mostly with statically typed languages, I'm unsure how to learn more about the `data` variable. I assume that it's analogous to an `InputStream`-type object, allowing me to read data as it becomes available, but I'm not sure.

Questions:

1. What type is the `data` object? What methods does it have?
2. How do Ruby developers typically go about investigating variables like this? I'm not sure I see a way to figure it out without writing a skeleton plugin and dumping a string representation of `data` to STDOUT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for writing an `input` plugin hints at this. From the [`run() method` section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_input_plugin.html#_literal_run_literal_method):

```
    data = $stdin.sysread(16384)
    @codec.decode(data) do |event|
      decorate(event)
      event.set("host", @host) if !event.include?("host")
      queue << event
    end
```

The `data` variable is a Ruby `String`, which is being used as a buffer of arbitrary bytes. I have verified this by creating a skeleton plugin and inspecting the value at runtime.

This seems to be cause for caution: the bytes provided to your `codec`'s `decode` method are not guaranteed to be a complete event.